# Use 2 different streams in one StreamBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter, stream, bloc

Use 2 different streams in one Stream Builder is this possible or how should I tackle this issue?

I tried using one stream for both of them but the BehaviorSubject for theme data is ThemeData model and for the languageStream a String and it is not working out.

```
child: StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: translationsBloc.languageOutStream,
//      stream: themeBloc.outFirestore,
```

these are the streams I want to use

the Blocs look like this:

```
 final _themeSubject = BehaviorSubject<ThemeData>();
  Stream<ThemeData> get outTheme => _themeSubject.stream;
```

and the other one like this

```
BehaviorSubject<String> _languageController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Stream<String> get languageOutStream => _languageController;
```

I need both streams to be in the main page as it affects the entire app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the best approach would be nested `StreamBuilders`. That is not uncommon and is actually used pretty often.

Of course you might load the inner stream only once `snapshot.data` is true for the first stream but that depends on your application. If you provide more code I'll help you with that. But the basic structure might end up like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: translationsBloc.languageOutStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        return StreamBuilder<ThemeData>(
            stream: themeBloc.outFirestore,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ThemeData> snapshot) {
              return Container();
            });
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage with a boolean variable `isThisStreamRequired`. set state of `isThisStreamRequired` on your condition.

```
child: StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: isThisRequired?translationsBloc.languageOutStream:themeBloc.outFirestore,
```