# How many StreamBuilders are too much?

Tags: flutter, dart

I couldn't find much resources as to how many StreamBuilders would start to cause problems for a users device.

Given that i am using multiple StreamBuilders, however the data there is not frequently updated. When it is however, it would be necessary for me that the data used is up to date, Hence why i did not use a FutureBuilder (incase a user has the page open and changes occur).

And so, i would imagine the answer would depend on the number of calls these StreamBuilders are getting, however what if they aren't being called often ?

Comment: how many? and how many streams do you have? so you mean that you would like to merge all of those streams and use just one `StreamBuilder`?

Comment: Let's say i have 3 streambuilders in a page and 2 other Streambuilders in the next two following pages when/if a user chooses to go for that path.  No i don't want to merge them i'm using nested streambuilders mainly as they're different streams. I'm just asking if let's roughly say 5-10 streambuilders that are rarely returning data would be too resource intensive.

Comment: nested, meaning you have 2 or more stream builders where the parent stream builder creates a child stream builder and so on?

Comment: Yes, like the answer mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709828/use-2-different-streams-in-one-streambuilder/55710349

Comment: in almost all cases you can use just one builder and transform your parent stream by calling `asyncExpand` or `transform` or similar `Stream` methods - in other words combine your data on data layer and not on UI layer

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the transform or asyncExpand methods however having nested streambuilders was recommended as a good solution by Remi Rousselet (Provider package creator) here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880330/flutter-stream-two-streams-into-a-single-screen  If i understood your critique correctly.

Comment: yep, but he later says: *"Another solution if this makes sense for you is: Streams are designed to be mergeable/transformed. You could make a third stream that is a merge of the two later streams.

Ideally for complex stream operations you'll want to use rxdart as it provides a few useful transformer."*

Comment: Yes i saw it, was just pointing out that the nesting method is also a good solution. Think we drifted a bit off topic here though, my question remains if having 5-10 streambuilders/streams that are rarely changed resource intensive.